# Python append specific times to list

Tags: python, linux, list, python-2.7, append

I am trying to append 5 times to a list and calculate the average of the values. Since the `top` command is looping forever, I am not able to do so.

```
#/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

values= []
cpu=subprocess.call(["top -b | awk '/sshd/ {print  $9}'"], shell=True)
values.append(cpu)
print values
```

Output:

```
3.0
0.3
2.3
2.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You need to use `subprocess.check_output` if you want `cpu` to have output of the command. `.call` does not return output of the command.

Second you can specify `-n 5` in you `top` command.

```
#/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

cpu = subprocess.check_output(["top -n 5 -b | awk '/sshd/ {print  $9}'"], shell=True)
values = cpu.split()
print values
```

Comment: `-n 5` doesn't work with xentop. Do you know any way solutions to that?

Comment: @user3580316 It is `-i 5` for "xentop".